# What's the difference between 마지막으로 and 드디어?

Tags: vocabulary

As the title says, what's the difference between 드디어 and 마지막으로? They're both "finally" but are they any different?

Comment: Just as a comment, heres another description of the difference from [TTMIK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzPtjJ7QfKk)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

마지막으로 indicates the last in a *series*. It also translates to "Lastly" in English.

드디어 is used like the expression, "finally!" and shows that there has been a long time waiting for something. Is similar to the usage of "finally" in the following examples:
- We finally arrived at our destination.
- I finally found you after so many years.
- You're finally done!

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to say "finally" in Korean, depending on the nuance. I will list a few more than you mentioned:

마지막으로 – literally "as the last", like the last item in a series

드디어 – finally (usually positive, something that I had been waiting for or that took a long time)
Ex. 드디어 합격했어요 (Finally I succeeded.)

결국에 – in the end, eventually (neutral, could also be negative with a reluctant feeling)
Ex. 결국에 그렇게 됐구나 (So in the end it has come to that.)

이제야 – at last (something that should have happened earlier, a slightly regretting feeling)
Ex. 이제야 공부해요 (Now, at last, I am studying)

Comment: is the '야' in 이제야 related to that in 해야하다?

Comment: @topomorto I don't think so. It's just emphasis, like in N+(이)야말로.